# Algorithm for word match percentage between two text files

Tags: java, algorithm

I have two Strings with many words in it.

My task is to find the percentage of word match between two strings. Can someone suggest me the algorithm we already have to get precise percentage/matched word.

**Example :**

```
1. Mason natural fish oil 1000 mg omega-3 softgels - 200 ea
2. Mason Vitamins Omega 3 Fish Oil, 1000mg. Softgels, Bonus Size 200-Count Bottle

**Output** should be 8 words matched between two strings.
```

Comment: How do you want to handle duplicates, e.g. if `fish` had appeared twice in both example strings, how would the count have been affected?

Comment: `tokenize` the sentences first, then diff the word using `contains()` or something? what you've tried..?

Comment: What is the algorithm "you already have"?

Comment: How did you come up with 8 matching words for the given example ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am sure you won't find duplicates.Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use method as below. I have added inline comments to discribe the each step you can try it. Note that on this code example I have used space character to split the words. If you have any concerns you can add comment.

Note that I have did the matching words **ignoring the case** because otherwise there was no possibility to have 8 matching words in your given example.

```
public static int matchStrings(String firstString, String SecondString) {

    int matchingCount = 0;

    //Getting the whole set of words in to array. 
    String[] allWords = firstString.split("\\s");
    Set<String> firstInputset = new HashSet<String>();

    //getting unique words in to set
    for (String string : allWords) {
        firstInputset.add(string);
    }

    //Loop through the set and check whether number of words occurrence in second String
    for (String string : firstInputset) {
        if (SecondString.toLowerCase().contains(string.toLowerCase())) {
            matchingCount++;
        }
    }
    return matchingCount;
}
```

Comment: Can you suggest me some inbuilt function to make my compilation time down.